# Select rows where specific field has value more than half of max value of the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, select-query

I'm wonder if there is a way to select rows where an specific field has value more than half of max value of the same field.

For example we have a result set with 3 fields (id, name, rate) that rate is an alias. If max rate is `70` so query should return all rows where `rate > 35` (that `35` is half of `70`).

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (A heavy and large select)as r WHERE r.rate > MAX(rate) / 2
```

Please note that i don't know what is the max rate and want to do it in a single query.

**update**
main select is a very heavy query and rate is an alias, so using subquery for max rate need to write that heavy query again.

Answer (score 4):

It's basically coded like you say it:

```
select * from mytable
where rate > (select max(rate) from mytable) / 2:
```

Comment: This actually do the job, but seems i asked my question so simple. So let me edit it.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cts as 
(select max(rate) as maxRate
from tableName 
)
select *
from tableName a join cts b 
on a.rate > maxRate/2
```

havent tested , but should work

and for mysql

```
select *
from tableName a join (select max(rate) as maxRate from tableName) b 
on a.rate > b.maxRate/2
```

Comment: oh, didnt spoted its mysql , my bad , sry ;/

Comment: My Fault friends, Seems i asked my question so simple. So i edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this untested code might work,

select id, name, rate
from table
group by id, name, rate
having rate > max(rate)/2;

Comment: Seems is a start point to solve the problem, Query executed but just 1 row returned. something need improvement.

Comment: This will not work.  The `rate` in the `having` clause is an arbitrary value from one row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table a
 INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
      id
      ,MAX(rate) / 2 AS max_rate 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE rate > max_rate
```